# Send an email if to a user registering in django when admin changes their account to is_active=True status

Tags: python, django

I am creating a register and login system in a project whereby on registering a users default is is_active=False. The admin then receives an email on user registering to approve or leave it inactive. on changing users status to is_active=True, the user should receive an email informing them they can now login.But i am not receiving any emails..or emails being sent, is there an error in my codes am failing to see??

> Here is my signals.py

```
from .models import AuthUser
from django.db.models import signals
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail

#signal used for is_active=False to is_active=True
@receiver(pre_save, sender=AuthUser, dispatch_uid='active')
def active(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_active and AuthUser.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk, is_active=False).exists():
        subject = 'Active account'
        message = '%s your account is now active' %(instance.username)
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [instance.email], fail_silently=False)

#signal to send an email to the admin when a user creates a new account
@receiver(post_save, sender=AuthUser, dispatch_uid='register')
def register(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', False):
        subject = 'Verificatión of the %s account' %(instance.username)
        message = 'here goes your message to the admin'
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [from_email], fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: Are the signals being executed? Or better question, how are you including the signal handles in the main execution pathway? Is it in the apps.py file, in the ready method(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.receiver)? What do you see in the server logs?

Comment: My signals.py is in my app.

Comment: i changed the location of the code for signals and put it in my models.py file..everything has worked out just fine now

Comment: i changed the location of the code for signals and put it in my models.py file..everything has worked out just fine now